# Windows 7 command to change share properties of a file or directory

Tags: windows-7, windows

On Windows 7 you have to right click a folder or file and press share with Everybody in order to share a file that has just been freshly written in the shared directory. It's a stupid setback in Windows 7....

Instead of doing all this by hand, I'd like to create a batch script to change the share properties of all the files in a directory to share with 'Everyone' .

Is there a windows command to change the share properties of a file/directory?

right click file -> share with -> specific people -> click drop down arrow -> click Everyone -> click Add -> select Everyone -> click Share -> click Done this is what i'm trying to emulate

Answer (score 1):

```
NET SHARE share$=<filepath>  /GRANT:user,permission
```

eg.

```
net share testshare=c:\folder /grant:everyone,full
```

You can type `net share` to see a list of shares.

Comment: what permission code do I need to put?

Comment: FULL. You can see the switches by typing 'net share /?'.

Comment: I don't see 'FULL' in the response.. to make it clear to me can you give example if file path was: c:/folder/ and I want to share with Everyone

Comment: Full is in the response.  The command was not dispayed in my answer properly, due to the markdown syntax on this forum. I've updated it.